# JESS function similar to findall in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, jess, prolog-findall

I am wondering if it is possible to write a jess function or rules to behave `findall` in Prolog.

For instance, we have a KB like

```
(person (name jason) (school nyu))
(person (name john) (school nyu))
(person (name liz) (school cmu))
...
```

and the input is `(school nyu)`, we want to collect all the names of person
like `[jason,john]`

Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a rule like this using the accumulate CE, or you can write it as a function using a defquery. Neither approach is using a rule engine the way it's really intended to be used, though; best to write a rule which matches one such entity and acts on it, and then let the rule fire once for each match.

Comment: Thanks! accumulate CE works well. I really appreciate your comments!